# (C++) how to i output the program sideways and like this

Tags: c++, nested-loops, repeat, do-while

I want a output like this:

Example input = 4

```
                         *
                  **    **
           ***   ***   ***
    ****  ****  ****  ****
```

its repeating the same with the pattern (row and column)

I already wrote the program, but I don't know how to show only the last column, until all columns are shown

This is the program I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int x;

int repeat = 0;

cin >> x;

do {
for (int b = 0; b <= x; b++)
{
    for (int c = b; c <= x; c++)
    {
    cout << " ";
    }
        for (int c = 0; c < b; c++)
        {
        cout << "*";
        }
cout << endl;
        }
        ++repeat;

    } while (repeat != x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: count number of spaces before star and just print them, before printing that star.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the exercise has two goals. It tries to teach you how to break down a task into smaller ones, and it asks you to print some `*` and spaces. I'll help you with the first but at least leave the lattter for you.

There is not only one way to divide a bigger problem into smaller ones. I will do the following: You want to print columns and rows made up of some pieces.

```
columns -> 
                     *   rows
              **    **   |
       ***   ***   ***   v
****  ****  ****  ****
                  ^--^ one piece
```

The `main` part can look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


std::string get_piece(int row, int col,int width);    

int main() {
    int x = 4;
    for (int row=0; row < x; ++row){
        for (int col = 0; col < x ; ++col){
            std::cout << get_piece(row,col,x) << "   ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

It prints `x` rows each with `x` columns. Now you just need to figure out the pieces. This is something to get started (it uses [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)):

```
std::string get_piece(int row, int col,int width){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(width) << std::setfill('x') << row << col;
    //    ^^ this is actually flawed, but you wont notice unless row or col are >9
    return ss.str();
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
xxx00   xxx01   xxx02   xxx03   
xxx10   xxx11   xxx12   xxx13   
xxx20   xxx21   xxx22   xxx23   
xxx30   xxx31   xxx32   xxx33
```

A completely different pattern you get with this implementation (this time using [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a character and the number to repeat that character):

```
std::string get_piece(int row, int col,int width){
    int num_stars = (row+col)/2;
    return std::string(num_stars,' ') + std::string(width-num_stars,'*');
}
```

It results in:

```
****   ****    ***    ***   
****    ***    ***     **   
 ***    ***     **     **   
 ***     **     **      *
```

Now you just have to figure out how the pieces have to look like depending on `row`, `col` and `width`.

Comment: `std::string(size, '*'`)` is more handy then `setw` and `setfill`.

Comment: @MarekR indeed, the idea was to have `col` and `row` in the output for ease of debugging. I'll think about how to add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to actually do it in reverse. Create this:

```
*
**
...
**** **** **** ****
```

and space-fill each line so that all your lines are the same length. But instead of printing each line from 0 to n, print them from n to zero. That is, you don't actually PRINT them that way -- you just build an array of strings, but then print the strings in reverse order.

The other choice is ahead of most of your current code, for each line, determine how many groups of stars shouldn't exist yet and then space-fill at the front. That would retain most of your existing code as it is.